# How do I make a batch file that will automatically press a key?

Tags: automation, batch-file, keystrokes

I want to create a simple batch file that will press a key automatically so that my computer won't automatically shut down after a long time of being away from the keyboard. Is that possible?

My operating system is Windows Vista.

Comment: Why not disable the automatic shutdown instead? Simulated key presses might not count as activity.

Comment: I think disabling them is somehow prohibited by a group policy or something like that so the question is still valid. Although you may use a tool to do that, you can also use one of your coins instead; just press any key (e.g. Print Screen, Insert, ...) whilst inserting a penny next to the key in press in order to keep the key pressed. (Be careful, not to touch any other key.)  This may look ugly, but is useful sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend going to the Power control panel and just setting your computer to never sleep or shutdown after an inactivity period.

If you still want to achieve what you specified, you can easily use a Windows Scripting Host (WSH) script, written in either JavaScript or VBScript.

1. Use the SendKeys method (i.e. `WSH.SendKeys("{f2}");`) to click a key in Windows Explorer.
2. Choose a key that will not cause an adverse action.
3. Use scheduler to run your script once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pressing keys, there are apps that will temporarily prevent your computer from going to sleep:

- [Don't Sleep](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/DontSleep)
- [Insomnia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/delay/give-your-computer-insomnia-free-tool-and-source-code-to-temporarily-prevent-a-machine-from-going-to-sleep)
- [Caffeine](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/index.html) (actually, this one works by simulating key presses)